# Suppressing Node.js warning for Mocha integration test?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocha.js

I have an Express application and I'm doing integration tests via Mocha.

For one piece of the test, I'm getting a `(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.` warning that's out of my control, as all EventEmitters are through third party modules.

Is there a way to suppress this warning while doing Mocha tests? Thanks.

Comment: there isn't enough information here to understand the source of the error (it might be an error in one of your dependencies), but I'd say that if you get that warning during tests, you shouldn't try to ignore it, but try to find what's causing it instead, because that might happen also while running your code in production.
if the error happens only while testing, then you should find the difference testing and production mode, as that's likely the real problem to address.

Comment: @Benja Hey, thanks for the response! I ended up discovering it was a significant problem with a third party module. It was a package that loaded mongoDB in memory, but didn't bother to wait for it to be loaded if your connection was slow. Woohoo!